# How to convert CDT time to IST time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a requirement where I get the data in Excel column like "Thu 6/25/19 6:29 AM" (CDT timing). Now I need to convert it into IST time of the same format.

Time difference between CDT and IST was 10hours 30minutes. I tried with this formula in excel - "=mod(A2+(10.5/24))" but it's not working. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Try `=A2 + TIME(10, 30, 0)`.

Comment: EXCEL's date-time does not carry any particular time zone with it; it can be relative to any time zone you desire.  The today() and now() functions are relative to whatever time zone your computer's system clock is showing, but even then EXCEL does not know or care what that is.  That leaves it up to you to provide interpretation of the time zone and add or subtract as many hours/minutes as needed to convert, as @Joe said above.